Добавить пробел в названия метки
Как вам идея добавить пробел в название меток?
Только надо сделать систему проверки, чтобы метки типо " " не допускались. Но типо этого - "функциональное программирование" допускались.
Ещё, если вы согласитесь с этой идей, может быть заменить все - в метках для разделения слов на пробелы?

Сейчас метки разделяются пробелами, поэтому они и не могут быть в именах. А вообще-то такому вопросу место скорее на MSE, мы здесь не можем менять функциональность сайта. Но я думаю, что там эта идея не вызовет поддержки: от её реализации сильно лучше не станет.

Вместо пробела есть "-" (тире), и этого достаточно для названий, у которых есть пробел.

Подобные предложения вряд ли могут быть реализованы исключительно для одного сайта, поэтому их следует размещать на MSE (на английском языке).
Но скорее всего это предложение будет отклонено. Например, какие проблемы в нём вижу я:

сейчас вводить несколько меток (при создании или редактировании вопроса) можно просто разделяя ввод пробелом, т.к. поле ввода одно на все метки. Как их вводить, если пробел будет допустим в составе метки? Требуется добавлять какой другой явный разделитель, например, обрамлять в квадратные скобки, как это делается в строке поиска.

многие сущности при программировании не допускают пробелов в именах, это неспроста, та же проблема с разделителем сущностей. Скорее всего затронет какие-то внутренние части кода, которые просто не видны обычному пользователю.

какие профиты мы получим, разрешая пробел в названии метки? Не могу придумать ничего кроме как "более естественное написание с точки зрения натурального языка"


С учетом имеющихся модераторских полномочий помечаю вопрос меткой статус-отклонено (без пробела!)
